# Full path to file

Tags: c++, qt, path

I make a video player and i need a full path to file that i'll open through QFileDialog. How to do it? Is there any functions for this in Qt? My present algorithm gives me only name of the file, not a full path.
My code for now:

```
void videoWindow::handleFile()
{
    *filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName();
    if (*filename != "D:\\фото\\video\\P1150278.MOV" | *filename != "")
    {
    video_enable(videoWid, *filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you wanted `||` instead of `|`

Comment: Why is `filename` a pointer?

Comment: Also `getOpenFileName()` returns a QString. As @LogicStuff just mentioned why is `filename` a pointer? Is that a pointer to a `QString`?? Seems very strange.

Comment: @drescherjm *filename is a QString from this class and i use a pointer to pass it to main window. So, in this case, that's not a pointer, but pointer dereference. The problem is not a pointer, but a full path to file.

Comment: `QString` returned by `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()` supposed to be full path, did you watch result under debugger and saw only name in `*filename`? Also, what are you trying to achive by this check `if (*filename != "D:\\фото\\video\\P1150278.MOV" | *filename != "")`. I also, likedrescherjm, suspect you wanted `||` there

Comment: ***`*filename` is a QString from this class and i use a pointer to pass it to main window.*** I would have used a signal / slot for that.

Comment: That works. The problem was not in this component, but in playlist and video playing component.

Comment: Maybe problem with source file encoding, you use "фото" - Cyrillic symbols.
Check that your source file encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: 1) Ensure you use text codecs correctly; 2) use `filename->isEmpty()` instead of `*filename == ""`; 3) use `||`; 4) (may be an answer) try `QFileInfo(*filename) == QFileInfo("path/to/compare")`. If you really need a full path, use `QFileInfo::absoluteFilePath`.

Comment: @ilotXXI I appreciate your help, but i've fixed it. Thanks a lot!